# Optimizar web pagespeed wordpress

Tags: wordpress, optimización

Trabajo en un equipo desarrllando webs en WordPress y queriamos ofrecer en el pack para nuestros clientes una buena optimización en el pagespeed de Google.

Mi duda es, si la plantilla es la misma, el servidor es el mismo y los plugins son casi los mismos, ¿se puede llegar a automatizar la configuración con los plugins necesarios, para que se pueda obtener en cada web una puntuación óptima (por ejemplo, 60 en movil mas o menos y 80 en ordenador) sin meter varias horas?

A ver si alguien tiene experiencia con pagespeed que me lo pueda confirmar (o no claro :) )

Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Pues va a depender de varias cosas. Si las webs son identicas, exactamente iguales, si, puedes optimizar una y que todas estén optimizadas, pero esto no es lo que hacéis. Supongo que cambiareis fotos, vídeos, textos...Si no están adaptadas siempre al tamaño adecuado, con la calidad adecuada y el formato correcto, olvídate. Por otro lado, va a depender de la plantilla que useis. Los temas de wordpress son bastante pesados, algunos, y no te darán buena velocidad de carga, aunque metas AMP y optimices. Vas a tener que meter mas que varias horas, si quieres cargar bien todo.

Comment: Dejo una sala de chat, porque esta pregunta se basará en opiniones y no es adecuada para tratar aquí. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91897/optimizar-wordpress

Comment: Yo me dedico a creación de webs con wordpress y algunas veces nos encontramos con este problema. La opción por la que optamos nosotros siempre es quitar el tema y su correspondiente plugin y hacer nuestra propia plantilla con únicamente lo necesario y mucho más optimizada. El resultado es increíble. SI dominas la creación de plantillas en una jornada puedes tenerlo resuelto sin problema.